# HTML5 Camera access - controlling the resolution

Tags: html, html5-video

I am using normal form input to access the camera on client phones like this:

```
<input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*" capture></input>
```

My question is: Can I control what quality/resolution the final video will be recorded in so I can reduce the size of the video being posted with the form?

Best regards
Jakob

Comment: In native HTML5, no such attribute/DOM interface appears in specification.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. I think it will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML Media Capture does not give you a way to do what you are looking for.

There is a new spec called getUserMedia.

Some documentation: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

[Here](https://jsbin.com/katoham) is a real demo of using the api. You would have to expand it to stream the video back to the server using sockets or webrtc or something. Go to it on a phone or something with a camera.

Below is a very raw example. Do not run the snippet here. I do that for formatting.

```js
// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var mediaConfig = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      facingMode: {
        //"user"
        //The video source is facing toward the user; this includes, for example, 
        //the front-facing camera on a //smartphone.

        //"environment"
        //The video source is facing away from the user, thereby viewing their environment. 
        //This is the back //camera on a smartphone.

        exact: "environment"
      },
      width: {
        min: 1920,
        ideal: 1920,
        max: 2900
      },
      height: {
        min: 1080,
        ideal: 1080,
        max: 2900
      }

    }
  };
  var errBack = function(e) {
    console.log('An error has occurred!', e)
  };

  // Put video listeners into place
  if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConfig).then(function(stream) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
    }).catch(this.errBack);
  }
  //Older browser support
  else if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
    navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream) {
      video.src = stream;
      video.play();
    }, errBack);
  } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream) {
      video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
    }, errBack);
  } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Mozilla-prefixed
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
    }, errBack);
  }

  // Trigger photo take
  document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap" class="sexyButton">Take Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```